# Twitter Integration in my application

Tags: iphone, ios5, sdk

I defined

```
#define kTwitterOAuthConsumerKey @"     Leu3YcKcTd4u2HsNw"
#define kTwitterOAuthConsumerSecret @"  zp6WwVn6FfOIYD4st6jjjGNT8Cy8tT84YA1HB9Cts"
```

The request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those leading spaces really part of your key/secret? Tried removing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define kTwitterOAuthConsumerKey @"Leu3YcKcTd4u2HsNw"
#define kTwitterOAuthConsumerSecret @"zp6WwVn6FfOIYD4st6jjjGNT8Cy8tT84YA1HB9Cts"
```

Just **remove all spaces** from the **ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret**, and place it as given by Twitter. I hope It will work for you.

Because I have tried by leaving space in my Consumer and Secret Key and I got same issue but after removing spaces, It authorized me.